# How to find %RAM and %CPU consumption of individual thread of running process in Linux?

Tags: linux, proc, ps, htop, process-monitoring

I creating an application for monitoring the thread of the running process.
I want to find out no of threading it running and CPU and RAM consumption of individual thread.

Comment: Asked and answered *ad nauseam*. You are expected to make an effort. Please show your code and state where you are having trouble. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158334) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of threads for a given pid:

```
$ ps -o nlwp <pid>
```

Where nlwp stands for Number of Light Weight Processes (threads). Thus ps aliases nlwp to thcount, which means that

```
$ ps -o thcount <pid>
```

does also work.

Percent of cpu usage per thread you can get with ps command:

```
 ps -emo %cpu,pid,user,args
```

The way it is calculated is described in ps manpage:

Currently, it is the CPU time used divided by the time the process has been running (cputime/realtime ratio), expressed as a percentage.

Memory is not allocated to threads, and often shared across threads. This makes it generally impossible to find the memory usage per thread.